# Vector norm with a full rank matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $|| . || $ be a vector norm on $R^m$ and assume $A$ is m by n. Show that if rank(A) = n, then $|| x ||_A$ = $|| Ax ||$ is a vector norm on $R^n$.
I know the 1, 2 and p-norm of a vector but don't understand how to go about here?

Comment: Didn't you forget to add some hypothesis concerning $m$ and $n$?

Comment: You need to check the axioms of the norm. Everything should be trivial except the axiom that the norm of a vector is zero iff it is the zero vector. Here is the part where you have to use the fact that the matrix has full rank.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I have checked there isn't any thing like that expect we know A is m by n.

Comment: @Mark, I know the axioms of norm. But, how to use them with a martix and how can ||x||_A = ||Ax||?

Comment: $||x||_A=||Ax||$ is just the definition of the norm. You need to use the fact that $||.||$ is a norm. For example why does the triangle inequality hold? We have $||x+y||_A=||A(x+y)||=||Ax+Ay||\leq||Ax||+||Ay||=||x||_A+||y||_A$. Now in a similar way you can check the other axioms.

Comment: O thank you so much. They should have put ':=' instead of '='.